# webview shows everytime the content of the last url when opening the app

Tags: android, url, webview

I have been looking for a simple way to go to the prevues page when I start my webview activity instead of opening the main page every time I open the activity .

I tried to save the prevues page using SharedPreferences but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call arbitrary methods on `Activity` until after `super.onCreate()` has completed. Move your `getSharedPreferences()` call inside of `onCreate()`, to be called after `super.onCreate()` has returned:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  settings = getSharedPreferences("URL", MODE_PRIVATE);
  settings.getString("url", "http://www.google.com"); 

  // rest of your code goes here
}
```

Comment: check my question I updated my code, now it doesn't crash but it only shows white screen.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize fields this way

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("URL", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

the call to `getSharedPreferences` is made when the object (currently the `Activity`) is initialized. The problem is that this particular method has to be executed when the `context` is ready. Currently the context object is the Activity itself. So if you want to load shared preferences, you have to wait the activity to created and then you are able to load them. Here comes the `onCreate` method. You can safely load any context dependant information here after calling `super.onCreate(...)`.